# css font icons not showing for everyone

Tags: html, css

I made my own website which works like fontawesome and I uploaded it on online server but there is a problem that no one can use my font icon and i want anyone to use my font icon

To use the font icon of my website, one has to link the css font as given below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/some-icons/icons/css/font.min.css">
```

When anyone is adding my website's font icon to his project, he is facing the problem.

[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptjPJ.png)

And when someone is downloading my font icon and doing it, then it is working.
[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/335Iz.png)

Here I have shown the font face of my own font icon with the help of css

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'font';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

    src: url('../fonts/font.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/font.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/font.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/font.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/font.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/font.svg?#font') format('svg');
}
.font
{
    font-family: 'font' !important;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    text-rendering: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: none;
    speak: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

So how can we fix this that anyone can use font icons from our website like fontawesome

so how can we allow font icon svg with .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]

Options All -Indexes


<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(svg|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$"> 
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Check your browser console probably is a CORS problem.

Comment: Please check your devtools network tab.  Probably your relative file paths/URLs are not correct. Check your file permission rules as well. Otherwise share a public css URL for debugging - there's no chance to help you without proper data/code examples.

Comment: @herrstrietzel This problem is happening only with .haccess, how can we fix it?

Comment: Then check your .htaccess directives ... or add it to your post

Comment: @herrstrietze .htaccess added

Comment: You CORS header looks OK. However the dev tools console and network tab should give you more details like "request blocked..." 404. Try to add a seperate .htaccess conatining only the `<ifModule>` rules to your fonts directory - maybe the other rewrite rules cause trouble. Otherwise please share the actual public css URL

Comment: also change the syntax of .htaccess like this .htaccess
<FilesMatch "\.(svg|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

Comment: @herrstrietze My website should also work like this website https://vicpra.com/

Comment: Please don't link to other websites to show what you're trying to achieve. Rather share your console messages or a public link to your font css for further debugging recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.
This problem was coming only from .htaccess syntax which is added like this and is also working.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(svg|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$"> 
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
</IfModule> 
</FilesMatch>
```